# Show stars rating with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to show a rating using 5 stars. I found different component that enable using stars to rate something, but not to show a rating. The problem is that the stars was selectable, so the user could change the value of the rating, like with this [component](https://github.com/Extrct/react-native-stars). Is there a solution to disable the touch from these element or is there another react component that only enables to show stars?

Comment: You can use the library you have used in your question and add a `disabled={true}` prop to `<Stars />`.

Comment: which lib are use right now for Rating? @j.doe

Answer (score 1):

You can disable touch via `pointerEvents` property. You can wrap the component you have mentioned in a View element like

```
<View pointerEvents="none">
  {stars}
</View>
```

If you don't want to use that component, simply add stars in a horizontal  view.

Answer (score 1):

There is a readonly prop that you can use to disable input. Also you can use isDisabled prop as well.

Have a look into [react-native-ratings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ratings)

```
1. npm i react-native-ratings

2. import { Rating } from "react-native-ratings";

3. <Rating defaultRating={3} ratingCount={5} size={5} readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

type ICustomRating = {
rating?: number;
disabled?: boolean;
onChange?: (arg: number) => void;
};

const CustomRating: React.FC<ICustomRating> = props => {

  const {rating = 0, disabled = false, onChange = () => {}} = props;
  const [defaultRating, setDefaultRating] = useState(rating);
  const maxRating = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const onStarClick = (item: number, bool: boolean) => {
  if (bool) {
    item = item - 1 + 0.5;
  }
  setDefaultRating(item);
  onChange(item);
 };

return (
  <View style={styles.ratingBarStyle}>
     {maxRating.map(item => {
        return (
          <View>
            <Image
             style={styles.imageStyle}
             source={
               item <= defaultRating
               ? Images.star
               : item >= defaultRating && item < defaultRating + 1
               ? Images.halfStar
               : Images.emptyStar
            }
          />
         {!disabled && (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.7}
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={() => onStarClick(item, true)}
            />

            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.7}
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={() => onStarClick(item, false)}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  })}
  </View>
 );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
  ratingBarStyle: {
   justifyContent: 'center',
   flexDirection: 'row',
   marginTop: 30,
  },
 imageStyle: {
  width: 40,
  height: 40,
  resizeMode: 'cover',
 },
 container: {
   flex: 1,
   flexDirection: 'row',
   position: 'absolute',
 },
 button: {
   width: 20,
   height: 40,
 },
});
```

[image]